# Typescript throwing type error unexpectedly

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I've done this exact execution of code several times prior to this but cannot seem to understand why it isn't working as usual. I understand that the types aren't being inferred but this error shouldn't occur usually? Unless I've made an error with the setup of my angular app.

[image]

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really not enough to make any educated guess here. What's `userData`? Are you using an IDE/editor? How have you setup your typings?

Comment: Your *if* is located where? Constructor / ngOnInit or where?
Look like its direct under your properties

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  And please consider providing a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your shared code block, it's not actually a code block.

If's go inside methods, your if is currently just floating around in your class.

```js
export class SomeClass {
    @Input() someInput: any;

    red: boolean = false;

    if (something) { ... }
}
```

vs

```js
export class SomeClass {
    @Input() someInput: any;

    red: boolean = false;

    someMethod(): void {
        if (something) { ... }
    }
}
```